# Couchbase Global Secondary Index (GSI) vs normal indexes

Tags: javascript, indexing, query-optimization, couchbase, nosql

I've been looking at the Global Secondary Index ability in Couchbase as of 4.0 and now improved to have auto rebalancing features in 5.0

In the video mentioned below, there are multiple benefits of GSI vs the normal secondary indexes that are usually stored in Map Reduce Views. GSI is node based, while Map Reduce Views are local and partition based.

It sounds like GSI is the silver bullet to all indexing solutions. Some of the notable benefits of Map Reduce Views are: 
* it's better for high data manipulation db - but GSI has the ability to defer build of indexes which lessens the issue, and also I tend to see queries getting more complicated and taking more time as compared to inserts.
* can make use of javascript for the indexing logic - which I think will only be for rare cases.

So will GSI be the default index if it's so good? 
I can't help but think small sized databases (ie. less than 1GB) shouldn't need GSI. It just sounds overly complicated.
Is there something I'm missing, a crucial point that will have people choosing normal indexes vs GSIs?

**References:**

- Video of GSI - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvjYKO27Vdk
- Auto rebalancing in version 5.0 - https://blog.couchbase.com/gsi-replicas-rebalancing/
- GSI info -
  https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/architecture/global-secondary-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

MapReduced views are preferred in some situations.

See this [Couchbase forum post](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/when-use-couchbase-views-instead-of-n1ql/3696/3?u=jkurtz) for details:

> Views will continue to be recommended for the following cases:
>
> 1. Using Javascript logic as part of the query
> 2. Performing aggregation (reduce), materializing the results, and then maintaing the results incrementally as the source data is modified.
>
> (2) is important for performance, because the aggregate results are essentially pre-computed.